# Adding new blocks to a catalog product view

Tags: catalog, addtocart, local.xml

I'm trying to add multiple blocks to the `right` template part of my product view.

I want to add the "add to cart" buttons and some other information there.

My `local.xml`:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/3columns.phtml</template>                
        </action> 
        <block type="core/text_list" name="newreference" as="newreference" translate="label">
            <label>New Reference</label>
        </block>            
    </reference>        
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="core/template" name="leftprice" template="catalog/product/leftdesc.phtml" before="-"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="core/template" name="rightprice" template="catalog/product/rightprice.phtml" />            
        <block type="core/template" name="addtocart" template="catalog/product/addtocart.phtml" />
        <block type="core/template" name="addto" template="catalog/product/addto.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

in `3columns.phtml`, I can load the `right` side template using `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?>` - this loads the template file `rightprice.phtml` correctly. My question is how/where can I properly load the `addtocart.phtml` and `addto.phtml` blocks?

I've tried loading them in the `rightprice.phtml` using `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('addto') ?>` as well as the getChildHtml method as well, but this loads nothing. I know I'm probably giving magento the wrong information in my `local.xml` file, but I can't replicate any working examples to load the add to cart functionality in a different place than where it is currently.

Comment: Have you enable the path hint.? Did you see the file is rendered?

Comment: Yeah, path hints are enabled, thats how I know rightprice.phtml is rendered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Right sidebar block type is `core/text_list` so it will automatically render the child blocks.

FYI: each block name should be unique.

In your code you have used the same block which is used by magento.

So try this

```
<reference name="right"> 
   <block type="core/template" name="rightprice" template="catalog/product/rightprice.phtml" /> 
   <block type="core/template" name="sidebar.addtocart" template="catalog/product/addtocart.phtml" /> 
   <block type="core/template" name="sidrbar.addto" template="catalog/product/addto.phtml" /> 
</reference>
```

Here I have change block name.

Enable the path hint. You can see all the file are render.